# Uvular Fricative Trill vs Uvular Fricative vs Preuvular Fricative

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation, consonants

I'm having trouble differentiating the uvular trill, uvular, and preuvular fricatives.

While I understand that the preuvular variant is more fronted, it sounds to me like many acclaimed uvular fricatives are actually raised, nonsonorant trills, [ʀ̝, ʀ̥˔]. That's at least what I've gathered from the speakers on *Rosetta Stone German* and the *Articulatory IPA* YouTube Channel ([voiced](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIFtLdajfKA), [voiceless](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0DaaB9RDUc)).

Is there any validity to my guess? Could someone please provide audio files of the three, so I could hear the difference? If the fricatives are audibly different, are the approximants?

I can make the voiced uvular trill, velar fricatives, and prevelar fricatives. It's only the uvular fricatives I'm having trouble distinguishing.

Comment: What's your native language? In English the diaeresis isn't usually used in the hiatus. (\*preüvular except for *naïve*).

Comment: I think I know what you mean. It is difficult to stop the uvula completely from vibrating during a uvular fricative. If there is mainly friction and no consistent vibration, someone might decide to use [ʁ ~ χ] instead. A real trill doesn't have as much friction as in your voiceless Youtube link and the recording definitely begins with a fricative.

Comment: I always think of Joe Gladwin when I think of a voiced uvular trill
https://youtu.be/LrXGA39XEvY?si=Cgon89miNa7tvEPB